# Suggested books to study statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, research-design

I am doing a research that requires me collecting and analyzing data samples in order to identify if there is correlation or no with respect to some parameter. I am looking for the best resources to study statistics and learn more about:

- What are the scientific methods for collecting samples to ensure that the sample is not biased.
- The significance of my results, i.e. are they significant or do not represent an actual correlation in the sample.
- Most important analysis to be conducted (e.g., confidence intervals).

Comment: Since all of what you mention is applied statistics, this really depends on your field of research.

Answer (score 1):

I won The Statistical Sleuth by Fred Ramsey as a book prize during school and since then I've lent it to several friends who were during research. I quite like it, it has a lot of applied examples. It also does not completely baby you through the concepts which is something I can't stand with a lot of introductory statistics books.

I just looked it up on Amazon and it's coming up as $170 CAD, eek. I would say its worth the investment though.